# Search Bar Filter Swift Done Searching

Tags: swift, uitableview, filter

I am trying to filter my array in my tableview to "contains" instead of "prefix" when searching.
Here is my code:

```
    var searching = false
    var cityArray = [["NYC, NY, New Hampshire"], ["Buffalo, NY"]]
    func reloadData() { 
    tableview.reloadData()
    }

    
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    searching = true
        searchCity = cityArray.flatMap({ $0 }).filter ({ 
        $0.lowercased().contains(searchBar.text!.lowercased())})
    reloadData()
    }
```

This function successfully does this. However, when I stop editing in the search bar, the tableview becomes blank without values and does not return the previous array prior to searching.

My Previous version of prefix allowed me to return the previous array no problem:

```
     func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
     searching = true
     searchCity = cityArray.flatMap({ $0 }).filter { $0.lowercased().prefix(searchText.count) == 
     searchText.lowercased()}
     reloadData()
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’ve changed to using searchBar.text rather than searchText.

The following should resolve your issue (not tested):

```
 func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
      searching = true
    searchCity = cityArray.flatMap({ $0 }).filter ({ 
    $0.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())})
    reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this I used this in combination with above.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `searching` to `false` if `searchText` is empty.

And `range(of` with `caseInsensitive` option is more efficient than the manual `lowercased` conversion

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchText.isEmpty {
        searching = false
        searchCity.removeAll()
    } else {
        searching = true
        searchCity = cityArray.flatMap({ $0 })
                              .filter{ $0.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil }

    }
    reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I used a variation of your solution and the solution below.

Comment: Originally I used your code but unfortunately I got an indexPath out of range error.

Comment: The error is not related to my code. In **all** data source and delegate methods you have to get the items from `cityArray` or `searchCity` depending on `searching`. And once again `contains` with `lowercased()` is less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I used the answers from above and meshed them together:

```
   func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
      if searchText.isEmpty {
        print("search Text is nil")
        searching = false
    } else {
        searching = true
        searchCity = cityArray.flatMap({ $0 }).filter ({ 
             $0.lowercased().contains( searchText.lowercased())})          
    }
    reloadData()
    }
```